TypeScript error in Next.js 15: Type 'DocPageProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'
I'm working on a Next.js 15 application and encountered the following TypeScript error:
app/(docs)/docs/[[...slug]]/page.tsx
Type error: Type 'DocPageProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'.
Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
Type '{ slug?: string[] | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]
for code here is repo link
'https://github.com/yakkshit/ui/blob/main/app/(docs)/docs/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D/page.tsx'
I tried async, await but still i'm getting the same error.
here is the code
interface DocPageProps {
  params: {
    slug?: string[];
  };
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}

async function getDocFromParams(params: DocPageProps['params']) {
  const slug = await params.slug?.join("/") ?? "";
  const doc = await allDocs.find((doc) => doc.slugAsParams === slug);

  if (!doc) {
    return null;
  }
  return doc;
}

export async function generateMetadata({
  params,
}: DocPageProps): Promise<Metadata> {
  const doc = await getDocFromParams(params);

  if (!doc) {
    return {};
  }

  return {
    title: `${doc.title} | Lingo UI`,
    description: doc.description,
    openGraph: {
      title: doc.title,
      description: doc.description,
      type: "article",
      url: absoluteUrl(doc.slug),
      images: [
        {
          url: doc.image,
          width: 1200,
          height: 630,
          alt: siteConfig.name,
        },
      ],
    },
    twitter: {
      card: "summary_large_image",
      title: doc.title,
      description: doc.description,
      images: [doc.image],
      creator: "@yakkshit",
    },
  };
}

export async function generateStaticParams(): Promise<
  DocPageProps["params"][]
> {
  return allDocs.map((doc) => ({
    slug: doc.slugAsParams.split("/"),
  }));
}

export default async function DocPage({ params, searchParams }: DocPageProps) {
  const doc = await getDocFromParams(params);

  if (!doc || !doc.published) {
    notFound();
  }

  const toc = await getTableOfContents(doc.body.raw);

